# Is there a way to write this LINQ query using lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, webforms

I have a linq query that I use to get data from 3 tables using 2 joins. I would prefer to write this as a lambda expression so my team finds it more readable. Is there a way to do this though? I can't find any decent examples.

```
var q = (
     from sus in susManager.Get()
     join su in suManager.Get() on sus.SUId equals su.Id
     join p in pManager.Get() on su.PId equals p.Id
     where sus.EndTimeStamp >= oneDayAgo
     select new
     {
         Name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
         Email = su.Email,
         LastLogIn = sus.StartTimeStamp,
         LastSessionDurationInMinutes = 
             DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(sus.StartTimeStamp, sus.EndTimeStamp),
         LastActive = sus.EndTimeStamp
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Lambda expressions are not more readable by any objective standard. It's for a reason that query syntax is also named "comprehension syntax".

Comment: @GertArnold I'm just following the style guide for the company.

Comment: Such style guides are nonsense. Nobody can force developers to abstain from readable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lambda equivalent would look something like this, assuming that the `Get()` functions return `List`s:

```cs
var q = systemUserSessionManager.Get()
    .Where(sus => sus.EndTimeStamp >= oneDayAgo)
    .Join(systemUserManager.Get(), 
        sus => sus.SystemUserId, 
        su => su.Id, 
        (sus, su) => new { sus, su })
    .Join(personManager.Get(), 
        j => j.su.PersonId, 
        p => p.Id, 
        (j, p) => new { sus = j.sus, su = j.su, p })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
        Email = su.Email,
        LastLogIn = sus.StartTimeStamp,
        LastSessionDurationInMinutes = 
            DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(sus.StartTimeStamp, sus.EndTimeStamp),
        LastActive = sus.EndTimeStamp
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this

```
var q = (
     from sus in systemUserSessionManager.Get()
     join su in systemUserManager.Get() on sus.SystemUserId equals su.Id
     join p in personManager.Get() on su.PersonId equals p.Id
     select new { sus = sus, su = su, p = p})
     .Where(x => x.sus.EndTimeStamp >= oneDayAgo)
     .Select(x => new {
         Name = x.p.FirstName + " " + x.p.LastName,
         Email = x.su.Email,
         LastLogIn = x.sus.StartTimeStamp,
         LastSessionDurationInMinutes = 
             DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(x.sus.StartTimeStamp, x.sus.EndTimeStamp),
         LastActive = x.sus.EndTimeStamp
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm assuming it's because you still have not converted all of the query syntax into lambda expressions.

Comment: My preferences are to leave the join as shown.  It is easier to read.